# making web application and frameworks a single package

Tags: .net, web-applications

I have developed a web application in asp.net in visual studio 2008.

Its working good in my local machines.

I have installed iis and also .net frameworks seperately in another system, and its working through the local host of that machine.

my question is can i make my web application and all .net framewoks as a single package.

so that it need not be installed seperately.

is any such way possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [Web Platform Installer (WPI)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebPlatformInstallerTryingToMakeItEasierToSetupForWebDevelopment.aspx) or [ClickOnce](http://www.edumax.com/c-sharp-basics-clickonce-deployment.html) or something a little different?